# How to check if Mono is empty?

Tags: spring, kotlin, project-reactor, reactive

I'm developing a app with Spring Boot 2.0 and Kotlin using the WebFlux framework.

I want to check if a user id exits before save a transaction. I'm stucked in a simple thing like validate if a Mono is empty.

```
fun createTransaction(serverRequest: ServerRequest) : Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val transaction = serverRequest.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(Transaction::class.java))

    transaction.flatMap {
        val user = userRepository.findById(it.userId)
        // If it's empty, return badRequest() 
    } 

    return transaction.flatMap { transactionRepository.save(it).then(created(URI.create("/transaction/" + it.id)).build()) }
}
```

It is possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 60):

The techniques that allow checking whether `Flux`/`Mono` is empty

Using operators `.switchIfEmpty`/`.defaultIfEmpty`/`Mono.repeatWhenEmpty`

Using mentioned operators you will be able to react to the case when Stream has been completed without emitting any elements.

First of all, remember that operators such `.map`, `.flatMap`, `.filter` and many others will not be invoked at all if there no `onNext` has been invoked.
That means that in your case next code

```
transaction.flatMap {
    val user = userRepository.findById(it.userId)
    // If it's empty, return badRequest() 
} 

return transaction.flatMap { transactionRepository.save(it).then(created(URI.create("/transaction/" + it.id)).build()) }
```

**will not be invoked at all, if `transaction` will be empty**.

In case if there is a requirement for handling cases when your flow is empty, you should consider operators like next in the following manner:

```
transaction
   .flatMap(it -> {
      val user = userRepository.findById(it.userId)
   })
   .swithIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> Flux.just(badRequest())));
```

## Actual solution

Also, I have noted that you created two sub-flows from the main `transaction`. Actually, following code will not be executed at all:

```
transaction.flatMap {
    val user = userRepository.findById(it.userId)
    // If it's empty, return badRequest() 
}
```

and will be only executed the last one, which is returned from the method. That happens because you ain't subscribed using operator `.subscribe(...)`.

The second point, you can't subscribe to the same request body more the one time (kind of limitation for `WebClient`'s reponse). Thus you are required to share your request body in the next way, so completed example will be:

```
fun createTransaction(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val transaction = serverRequest.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(Transaction::class.java)).cache()

    transaction
            .flatMap { userRepository.findById(it.userId) }
            .flatMap { transaction.flatMap { transactionRepository.save(it) } }
            .flatMap { ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/transaction/" + it.id)).build() }
            .switchIfEmpty(transaction.flatMap { ServerResponse.badRequest().syncBody("missed User for transaction " + it.id) })
}
```

Or more simple case without sharing transaction flow but using `Tuple`:

```
fun createTransaction(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val emptyUser = !User()
    val transaction = serverRequest.body<Mono<Transaction>>(BodyExtractors.toMono(Transaction::class.java))

    transaction
            .flatMap { t ->
                userRepository.findById(t.userId)
                        .map { Tuples.of(t, it) }
                        .defaultIfEmpty(Tuples.of(t, emptyUser))
            }
            .flatMap {
                if (it.t2 != emptyUser) {
                    transactionRepository.save(it.t1)
                            .flatMap { ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/transaction/" + it.id)).build() }
                } else {
                    ServerResponse.badRequest().syncBody("missed User for transaction " + it.t1.id)
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't compile... Could you check it? Also, there is no badRequest method with a string parameter.

Comment: @voliveira, Could you point me to which language this example has been written since I just tried to follow your code convention

Comment: @voliveira89 fixed

Comment: Doesn't compile also! The example you gave (that is totally equals to what I wrote in my code) makes sense, but intellij raise a error in the bracket that closes the function: "A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')"

Comment: could you please point me to the particular line in the code snippet above?

Comment: The last line of the first solution (the one that you edited).

Comment: I have a issue where I need to return an empty Mono according to a condition. Further code flow is dependent on this empty Mono, How do I make sure if it returning an empty Mono?

Comment: @shapan-dashore you may use `log` operator after your flatMap to ensure that it emits only `onComplete` signal. Otherwise, if you need some fallback logic - you may put `defaultIfEmpty` operator which can handle the empty scenario and do something about it as a fallback

Comment: `Mono.fromFuture(() -> client.getItem(request))
                .map(GetItemResponse::item)
                .filter(item -> !item.isEmpty())
                .map(item -> ItemData.builder()
                        .data(item.get("value").s())
                        .etag(item.get("etag").s())
                        .build())`
I will try the log operator but from a cursory look at the above code what would it return if `item` object is empty, I want this to return an empty Mono.

Answer (score 7):

You can check it using the Mono's provided method *hasElement()* which is analogous to Optional's *isPresent()*. The method definition is :

```
Mono<Boolean> hasElement()
```

for more details checkout : [project reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#hasElement--)

In case you have to perform some action based on this value you can further use switchIfEmpty() to provide with alternate publisher.

Answer (score 3):

Use Mono with Optional:

```java
return findExistingUserMono
  .map(Optional::of)
  .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty())
  .flatMap(optionalUser -> {
    if(optionalUser.isPresent()) {
      return Mono.error('xxxx');
    }
    return this.userService.create(optionalUser.get());
  });
```

This way it will always emit Optional value so that the stream will never break.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying I am a newbie on reactive (java) and on this forum.
I think you cannot really check in this code if a mono is empty because a mono represents code that will be executed later on, so in this code body you won't know yet if its is empty. Does that make sense?

I just wrote something similar in Java which seems to work (but not 100% this is the best approach either):

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> queryStore(ServerRequest request) { 

        Optional<String> postalCode = request.queryParam("postalCode");                            

        Mono<ServerResponse> badQuery = ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
        Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound().build();

        if (!postalCode.isPresent()) { return  badQuery; }

        Flux<Store> stores = this.repository
                .getNearByStores(postalCode.get(), 5);

        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(stores, Store.class)
                .switchIfEmpty(notFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use switchIfEmpty method for this

Below example, I'm checking if the user exists with email if not then add it

```
userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                .switchIfEmpty(s -> {
                    user.setStatus("InActive");
                    String encodedPassword = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(user.getPassword());
                    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
                    userRepository.save(user).subscribe();
                    s.onComplete();
                }).then(Mono.just(user));
```

Comment: There is no method with the signature `switchIfEmpty(Consumer<T>)`. There is only  `switchIfEmpty(Mono<? extends T> alternate)`, see https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-